# Identifier already declared for non existing line

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I imported a component `getPatientsbyMedic` from `getPacientbyMedic.js`, but now I don't use it anymore so I had that line commented. No all of the sudden, I keep getting this error:

`Parse errors in imported module '../medics/ApprovedMedic/PreScreenings/AnswerPreScreening': Line 23: Identifier 'getPatientsbyMedic' has already been declared.`

I since then have deleted the line, uncomment and re-commented it, and I still get this error and I am still unable to run my front-end. How do I fix this?

Comment: We need to see the import lines in the file that triggers this error